# Filtering Java ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am working on ecom application. My product is defined below:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Product {
    private String productId;
    private String brand;
    private String description;
    private BigDecimal price;

    public String getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(String productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }

    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPrice() { return price; }

    public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) { this.price = price; }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Product product = (Product) o;
        return productId.equals(product.productId);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(productId);
    }
}
```

I have a Cache object defined as below to persist my product objects as:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class Cache<K, V> extends ConcurrentHashMap<K, V> {

    private static final int MAX_SIZE = 2;

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        return super.size() < MAX_SIZE ? super.put(key, value) : null;
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
        if(MAX_SIZE > (super.size() + m.size())){
            super.putAll(m);
        }
    }

    public Cache<K, V> getByBrand(String brand) {
        return super.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getValue().getBrand().equals(brand));
    }
}
```

And, I persist my product in the above cache as:

```
@Repository
public class ProductRepository {

    private Map<String, Product> products = new Cache<>();

    public void addProduct(Product product) {
        products.put(product.getProductId(), product);
    }

    public Product getProduct(String productId) {
        return products.get(productId);
    }

    public List<Product> getProductByBrand(String brand) {
        return products.getByBrand(brand);
    }

    public Collection<Product> getAll() {
        return products.values();
    }
}
```

However, when I am trying to run this code, it does not even compile. It is failing on `return products.getByBrand(brand);` with the following error:

```
cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method getByBrand(java.lang.String)
```

How would I code this correctly?

Comment: `Stream.filter()` returns `Stream`, not `Cache`.

Comment: You are declaring `Map<String, Product> products;` and then calling `products.getByBrand(String)`. This is not possible because `Map<String, Product>` does not have this method. This is similar to how `Object o = "Hello World"; o.substring(0, 6);` will fail. You should declare it as `Cache<String, Product> products` instead

Comment: The error suggests that the code that is actually running is not the one you think.
Make sure to clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: Note that `put()` breaks the contract, and `putAll()` can be overly strict if there are duplicated keys in `m`.

Comment: @thatotherguy, `Map` is an interface and he explicitly initializes `products` as a `Cache` object. This is similar to something like `List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();` and then calling a method unique to the implementation of `ArrayList`

Comment: @ErikKarlstrand It doesn't matter whether the supertype is an interface or class. It's invalid either way in Java.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the problem is near `super.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getValue().getBrand().equals(brand));` @ErikKarlstrand unfortunately the problem is something to be resolved by running clean.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do or why you'd expect it to work.

Comment: i am tryning to have `getProductByBrand()` return `List<Product>` where products brand matches the supplied string.

Comment: You can't do it inside your `Cache` class, because it doesn't know what `V` is. But you can do this externally: `products.values().stream().filter(p -> p.getBrand().equals(brand)).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: 'Cannot find symbol' is not a [tag:syntax] error, but it is one of the [tag:compiler-errors].

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

Your repository should know about brands and products, not your custom collection `Cache` class.

```
@Override
public Collection < Product > getProductsByBrand ( String brand ) {
    return this.mapProductIdToProduct.values().stream().filter( product -> product.brand().equals( brand ) ).toList();
```

## Move `getByBrand` to repository

As [commented by shmosel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68733180/filtering-java-concurrenthashmap#comment121471691_68733180), your main problem is locating the `getByBrand` method in the wrong class.

Your `ConcurrentHashMap` subclass `Cache` is generic, meant to handle any type for its key and its value. But your `getByBrand` method assumes the objects in the collection are of `Product` class. Therefore that method is a misfit, does not belong there. `Cache` is not meant to be aware of brands and products.

Where that method does belong is in your repository code, `ProductRepository`. That class is built to work specifically with `Product` objects. Whether your repository class uses your subclass of `ConcurrentHashMap` is an implementation detail that should be unknown to the other parts of your app that are trying to work with `Product` objects.

### Make `ProductRepository` an interface, not class

Therefore you have another problem: A repository should usually be an interface, not a concrete class. The purpose to having a repository in a design is to insulate the business logic of the app from the underlying data storage facts. The user-interface and business logic areas of your app should not (generally) care whether your repository is retrieving `Product` data from your `Cache` class, a database, or a file on disk storage. By using an interface for your `Repository` you can develop various implementations. One implementation might be quick and dirty, with hard-coded data, to use as you begin development. Then eventually you write implementations for testing that load pre-configured test data in text files. And eventually you write yet another implementation that loads real data from a database.

```
[user-interface] <--> [business-logic] <--> [repository-interface] <--> [repository-concrete] <--> [memory/storage/database]
```

So your repository interface would look like this.

```java
package work.basil.coll;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Optional;

public interface ProductRepository {

    public void addProduct ( Product product );

    public Optional <Product> getProduct ( String productId );

    public Collection < Product > getProductsByBrand ( String brand );

    public Collection < Product > getAll ();
}
```

Notice that we wrapped the return value from `getProduct` in an `Optional`. This signals to the calling method that we may not find a match to return.

And I changed `List` to `Collection` as the return type of `getProductsByBrand` to match what you did on `getAll`.

And a minor quibble: Your method `getProductByBrand` name should be plural, with `s` in the middle, `getProductsByBrand`.

### Implement repository interface

And here is an implementation of that interface using an in-memory `Set`. I used a regular `Set` here as you did not explain what the purpose of your map subclass; I don’t know what the keys and values would be in the context of your example.

```java
package work.basil.coll;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Set;

public class CachedProductRepository implements ProductRepository {
    // Fields
    private Set < Product > products;

    // Constructor
    public CachedProductRepository () {
        this.products = new HashSet <>();
    }

    // ---------| Implements `ProductRepository`  |---------------------

    @Override
    public void addProduct ( Product product ) {
        this.products.add( product );  // Ignoring the boolean return value.
    }

    @Override
    public Optional < Product > getProduct ( String productId ) {
        return this.products.stream().filter( product -> product.productId().equals( productId ) ).findAny(); // May or may not find a match. So return an `Optional`.
    }

    @Override
    public Collection < Product > getProductsByBrand ( String brand ) {
        return this.products.stream().filter( product -> product.brand().equals( brand ) ).toList(); // Return unmodifiable collection.
    }

    @Override
    public Collection < Product > getAll () {
        return Set.copyOf( this.products );  // Return an unmodifiable set, copied from our original set.
    }
}
```

We can define the `Product` class as a Java 16+ [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395), for brevity. You could just as well use a conventional class.

```java
package work.basil.coll;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

public record Product( String productId , String brand , String description , BigDecimal price ) { }
```

### Demo code

And here is some code to demonstrate.

```java
Set < Product > products =
        Set.of(
                new Product( "HD101" , "HandyDandy" , "Wonder Widget Standard" , new BigDecimal( "11.00" ) ) ,
                new Product( "HD202" , "HandyDandy" , "Wonder Widget Deluxe" , new BigDecimal( "19.00" ) ) ,
                new Product( "HD303" , "HandyDandy" , "Wonder Widget Platinum" , new BigDecimal( "42.00" ) ) ,
                new Product( "MCA1" , "MegaCorp" , "Dazzling Doodad Alpha" , new BigDecimal( "7.00" ) ) ,
                new Product( "MCB1" , "MegaCorp" , "Dazzling Doodad Beta" , new BigDecimal( "17.00" ) )
        );
ProductRepository productRepository = new CachedProductRepository();
for ( Product product : products ) {
    productRepository.addProduct( product );
}

Collection < Product > handyDandyProducts = productRepository.getProductsByBrand( "HandyDandy" );
```

When run.

> productRepository.getAll() = [Product[productId=HD101, brand=HandyDandy, description=Wonder Widget Standard, price=11.00], Product[productId=HD202, brand=HandyDandy, description=Wonder Widget Deluxe, price=19.00], Product[productId=MCA1, brand=MegaCorp, description=Dazzling Doodad Alpha, price=7.00], Product[productId=MCB1, brand=MegaCorp, description=Dazzling Doodad Beta, price=17.00], Product[productId=HD303, brand=HandyDandy, description=Wonder Widget Platinum, price=42.00]]
>
> handyDandyProducts = [Product[productId=HD202, brand=HandyDandy, description=Wonder Widget Deluxe, price=19.00], Product[productId=HD101, brand=HandyDandy, description=Wonder Widget Standard, price=11.00], Product[productId=HD303, brand=HandyDandy, description=Wonder Widget Platinum, price=42.00]]

### Update - Map-backed cache

Upon re-reading the Question again, I came to see you were intending to use your `Map` sub-class to track product by ID, a `Map< String , Product >`.

Actually my misunderstanding makes for a nice example of my point about defining your repository as an interface so you can swap out various implementations. Here is another implementation to swap out for my first. Here we use a map-backed collection of products internally to track the products.

```java
package work.basil.coll;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentNavigableMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap;

public class MapBackedProductRepository implements ProductRepository {
    // Fields
    private ConcurrentNavigableMap < String, Product > mapProductIdToProduct;

    // Constructor
    public MapBackedProductRepository () {
        this.mapProductIdToProduct = new ConcurrentSkipListMap <>();
    }

    // ---------| Implements `ProductRepository`  |---------------------

    @Override
    public void addProduct ( Product product ) {
        this.mapProductIdToProduct.put( product.productId() , product );  // Ignoring the returned `Product` value.
    }

    @Override
    public Optional < Product > getProduct ( String productId ) {
        return Optional.ofNullable( this.mapProductIdToProduct.get( productId ) ); // May or may not find a match. So return an `Optional`.
    }

    @Override
    public Collection < Product > getProductsByBrand ( String brand ) {
        return this.mapProductIdToProduct.values().stream().filter( product -> product.brand().equals( brand ) ).toList(); // Return unmodifiable collection.
    }

    @Override
    public Collection < Product > getAll () {
        return Set.copyOf( this.mapProductIdToProduct.values() );  // Return an unmodifiable set, copied from our original set.
    }
}
```

I used `ConcurrentSkipListMap`, a `ConcurrentNavigableMap`, to hold our `Product` collection. You could experiment with using your custom `Cache` class instead.

Notice how when we switch our repository concrete implementation, we need not change any of our other code — nothing breaks.

```java
Set < Product > products =
        Set.of(
                new Product( "HD101" , "HandyDandy" , "Wonder Widget Standard" , new BigDecimal( "11.00" ) ) ,
                new Product( "HD202" , "HandyDandy" , "Wonder Widget Deluxe" , new BigDecimal( "19.00" ) ) ,
                new Product( "HD303" , "HandyDandy" , "Wonder Widget Platinum" , new BigDecimal( "42.00" ) ) ,
                new Product( "MCA1" , "MegaCorp" , "Dazzling Doodad Alpha" , new BigDecimal( "7.00" ) ) ,
                new Product( "MCB1" , "MegaCorp" , "Dazzling Doodad Beta" , new BigDecimal( "17.00" ) )
        );
ProductRepository productRepository = new MapBackedProductRepository();  // new CachedProductRepository();
for ( Product product : products ) {
    productRepository.addProduct( product );
}

Collection < Product > handyDandyProducts = productRepository.getProductsByBrand( "HandyDandy" );
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with the code provided:

1. The reason the compiler reports "cannot find symbol" for `getByBrand` is that the `products` field is declared with the type `Map<String, Product>`, even though the runtime type is actually `Cache`. When you declare a variable to have a particular type, you can only reference methods that are declared on that type or super types, but in this case you are trying to use a method from a subtype. You can fix this by changing the declaration:

   ```
   private Cache<String, Product> products = new Cache<>();
   ```
2. The `Cache` class is declared to handle arbitrary types of keys and values, using Java generics to declare the types as `K` and `V`. This means that you cannot assume in that class that the values have the type `Product`, and therefore cannot call methods on the values that are declared in `Product` such as `getBrand`. If you want to declare `getByBrand` as a member of `Cache`, you'll need to declare the `Cache` class as having values of type `Product`:

   ```
   public class Cache<K> extends ConcurrentHashMap<K, Product> {
   ```

   Then, replace all uses of `V` with `Product`, and remove it from the declaration of the `products` variable in `ProductRepository`:

   ```
   private Cache<String> products = new Cache<>();
   ```
3. Then, the return type of `Cache.getByBrand` doesn't match either the type of the value returned, or the type expected by the caller `ProductRepository.getProductByBrand`. Assuming that you want to actually have it return `List<Product>`:

   ```
   public List<Product> getByBrand(String brand) {
       return super.values().stream()
               .filter(product -> product.getBrand().equals(brand))
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
   }
   ```

After these changes, the code compiles. However, there are some other things to think about:

1. As written, once the cache reaches its maximum size, it silently drops any items that you try to add with `put` or `putAll`. This is surprising behavior, and it's unclear how this should work within the context of the rest of the application. Right now, this isn't really being used as a cache, but rather a collection of all of the products in the repository. In a realistic application, you would probably store products in a database, but then you would want your cache to have some way to clear older entries when newer ones are added (typically called "cache eviction").
2. The checks for the maximum size in the `Cache` class are not thread safe. It's possible for two concurrent executions of `put` or `putAll` to cause the map to exceed `MAX_SIZE`. This is because the size check and addition of the value to the map are not atomic: it's possible for one thread to do the size check just before another one adds a product. Because both threads have checked the size before either one adds the product to the map, both will proceed with adding their product. Fixing this would be tricky without introducing locking, which limits concurrency.
3. The `getByBrand` method iterates through all of the products in the cache. If this is in fact used as a cache, rather than a container for all  of the products in the repository, this will most likely give incomplete results. It will also slow down as the collection of products in the cache grows... not such a problem with a `MAX_SIZE` of 2, but in a more realistic scenario could become a problem.

If you are planning to use a database to hold product data, I would encourage you to look at existing caching solutions. Most Java developers would use an ORM solution such as Hibernate to do database access, or another library that provides database access abstractions. Most of these will have their own solutions for caching.